# How to configure circuit breaker in celery 5

Tags: celery, circuit-breaker

Celery 5 introduces the concept of Ciruit Breaker into the framework [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/celery-enhancement-proposals/en/latest/draft/celery-5-high-level-architecture.html#circuit-breaking).

Anyone knows how to configure the circuit breaker ? An example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not trust a two years old document (*Last-Modified
2019-04-08*) to reflect the current state of Celery. Moreover, the document contains enhancement ideas - it is not a changelog or similar.